# How to run node.js app by grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs

Folder structure:-

myapp

--public(directory) //here files which related to public(Angularjs,css,etc)

--server(directory) //here files which related to server

--server.js

**Code**

```
server.js //at root directory
----------------------
...
var app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // set the static files location
app.use('/profilepic', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads/profilepic')); // set the static files location
app.use('/company', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads/company'));
app.use('/download', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads/download'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./server/config/passport')(app, passport);
require('./server/route')(app, passport);
app.use(flash());
if (config.env === 'development') {

    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    });

}

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
});


app.listen(config.port, function() {
    console.log('app listen on ' + config.port);
});





Gruntfile.js //at root directory
-----------------
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        jshint: {
            options: {
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish') // use jshint-stylish to make our errors look and read good
            },

            // when this task is run, lint the Gruntfile and all js files in src
            build: ['Grunfile.js', './']
        },
        ngAnnotate: {
            options: {
                singleQuotes: true
            },
            app: {
                files: {
                    './dist/min-safe/services.js': ['./public/scripts/services/*.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/filters.js': ['./public/scripts/filters/*.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/directives.js': ['./public/scripts/directives/*.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/controllers.js': ['./public/scripts/controllers/*.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/app.ctrl.js': ['./public/scripts/app.ctrl.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/config.router.js': ['./public/scripts/config.router.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/config.lazyload.js': ['./public/scripts/config.lazyload.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/config.js': ['./public/scripts/config.js'],
                    './dist/min-safe/app.js': ['./public/scripts/app.js']
                }
            }
        },
        concat: {
            js: { //target
                src: ['./dist/min-safe/app.js', './dist/min-safe/config.js',
                    './dist/min-safe/config.lazyload.js', './dist/min-safe/config.router.js',
                    './dist/min-safe/app.ctrl.js', './dist/min-safe/controllers.js',
                    './dist/min-safe/directives.js', './dist/min-safe/filters.js', './dist/min-safe/services.js'
                ],
                dest: './dist/min/lms.js'
            }
        },
        copy: {
            main: {
                expand: true,
                src: './dist/min/lms.js',
                dest: './public',
                flatten: true,
                filter: 'isFile'
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                base: 'xxxxxxxx',
                keepalive: true
            }
        },

    });

    // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ng-annotate');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['ngAnnotate', 'concat', 'copy']);
    grunt.registerTask('server', ['default', 'connect']);
    grunt.registerTask('jshint', ['jshint']);

};
```

I run app by `node server.js` but now i want to run this app by grunt and when i run `grunt server` the it throw **No "connect" targets found** error.

How to configure grunt file to run app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When i run grunt server the it throw **No "connect" targets found** error. How to configure grunt file to run app?

In your `Gruntfile.js` update the `connect` [Task](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) to include a [Target](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) as follows:

```js
// ...
connect: {
    server: { // <-- This is a Target named 'server'.
        options: {
            // <-- Your connect options go here.
            //     https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#options
        }
    }
}
```

Next update your `grunt.registered.Task()` named `server` to this:

```js
grunt.registerTask('server', ['default', 'connect:server']);
```

***Note:*** Instead of aliasing the `connect` Task in the `taskList` `Array` it now references the `server` Target in the `connect` Task using the syntax `'connect:server'`

See [Creating Tasks](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#creating-tasks) for further information regarding `grunt.registered.Task()`.

---

**EDIT**

***Updated based on feedback in the comments and edit made to original post/question:***

Assuming that running `$ node server.js` via your CLI works as expected you can run the same command via grunt.

1. Uninstall `grunt-contrib-connect` by running:

`$ npm un -D grunt-contrib-connect`

2. Delete line of code reading `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');` from `Gruntfile.js`
3. Delete the `connect` Task from `Gruntfile.js`
4. Run the following to install [load-grunt-tasks](https://github.com/sindresorhus/load-grunt-tasks) and [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell):

`npm i -D load-grunt-tasks grunt-shell`

5. Add the following Task to `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
// ...
shell: {
    connect: {
        command: 'node server.js'
    }
}
// ...
```

6. Change the current `grunt.registerTask()` to:

```js
grunt.registerTask('server', ['default', 'shell:connect']);
```

7. Add the following line of code to `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

8. Run `$ grunt server` and visit `localhost:3000`

Comment: thanks @Robc , `Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, stat  '/home/clsah/projects/../server.js/' at Error (native)` throw an error, it is connect code `connect: {server:{options: {base: 'server.js', keepalive: true}}}`. here `connect base` treat `server.js` as directory.

Comment: When you run `$ node server.js` via the CLI and visit `localhost:XXXX` in your browser does your site load? What port number does `config.port` reference ? Is it 3000 ?

Comment: yes, it's 3000. I think i am unable to put my problem. Look, Is it possible to run app by `grunt` ? So, i can visit app at `localhost:3000`

Comment: **Updated answer** based on edits to question and comments.

Comment: @RobC Is possible to run a node server with different port like 8081 instead of 3000 using this approach ?

Comment: @Arunprasad - You should be able to explicitly hardcode the port you want to use by specifying it in your _server.js_ file, i.e. Assuming your using `express` as per the original question above you'll need to add the following line to _server.js_: `app.set('port', 8081);`